# How to override css media class?

Tags: html, css

I use some css library for my project.

This library has this class:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .nav-tabs>li {
        margin-bottom:3px;
    }
    .nav-tabs>li,
    .nav-tabs>li>a {
        display:block !important;
        float:none !important;
        border:0 !important;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
    }
    .nav-tabs>li>a :focus,
    .nav-tabs>li.active>a {
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    }
}
```

When the size of the screen is smaller then `480px` the `li` elements layouts is changes.

I need change the default behavior when the size of the screen is smaller then `280px`(override - max-width: 480px ).

I dont want to change original's library file so I pasted this class:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 280px) {
    .nav-tabs>li {
        margin-bottom:3px;
    }
    .nav-tabs>li,
    .nav-tabs>li>a {
        display:block !important;
        float:none !important;
        border:0 !important;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
    }
    .nav-tabs>li>a :focus,
    .nav-tabs>li.active>a {
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    }
}
```

inside my custom css file.

But still I get default behavior and `li` elements layouts is changes only when size of the screen is smaller then `480px`.

Any idea why I cant override the CSS class above?

Comment: I don't see any difference in the actual styles.

Comment: @Blazemonger the difference in the width 280px not 480px

Comment: You souldn't worry about screen sizes below 320px: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74798/are-there-devices-narrower-than-320px-and-data-on-their-usage-for-web-browsing

Comment: Is your css called after the other css?

Comment: `max-width: 480px` includes `max-width: 280px` already, since `280 < 480`. And since the CSS in each media query is the same, nothing on your page is going to change when you go from `480px` to `280px`

Comment: ... and therefor, if you can’t/don’t want to remove the original media query - then you need to copy that one as well, and overwrite the values you don’t like.

Comment: @CBroe, that exactly what I tried  to do.But I don't get get any desired result.

Comment: Well then show us what you tried, and properly describe how exactly it fails and where.

Comment: You need to post the shortest code necessary to reproduce the issue or else all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some rules for less than 280pixels and some other rules between 280 and 480. Right?

```
@media (max-width:480px) and (min-width:281px) { 

}
```